# How to use an array in React and convert to component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've created a webpage that pools from a SQL database I generated that has info such as a person's name, address and job. I figured out how to display this on the webpage by creating an array and putting the data into it to then return. What I want to do is create a react component that looks like a tile/nametag and is a box containing each person/job and have it be created for each entry. I am confused on how I would create the react component and style it with CSS.

here is my webpage code:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Dashboard extends Component {
    displanyName = Dashboard.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            people: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("api/people")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ people: data }));
    }
    render() {
        //const { people } = this.state; // equivalent to next line
        const people = this.state.people;
        if (people.length > 0)

        //creates an array to iterate
        let arr = people.map((person, index) => <div key={index}>Person: {person.name} , Job: {person.job}</div>);

        return (
            <div>
                {arr}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

That displays the contents of the array on the page like this:
Person: Bob Bobbert , Job: Programmer
Person: Jane Doe , Job: Teacher
Person: John Smith , Job: Chef

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can try this.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class PersonNameJob extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Person: {this.props.person.name}, Job: {this.props.person.job}</div>
    );
  }
}

export class Dashboard extends Component {
  // more code here...
  render() {
    const people = [
      {
        name: 'John',
        job: 'Developer',
      },
      {
        name: 'Marry',
        job: 'accountant',
      },
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        {people.map((person, index) => (<PersonNameJob key={index} person={person} />))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Dashboard />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

You can style directly by using style attributes of a Component or use [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) package.

```
export class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    // logic to get people
    return (
      <div>
        {people.map((person, index) => (<StyledPersonNameJob key={index} person={person} />))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const StyledPersonNameJob = styled(PersonNameJob).`
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid #000;
`;
```

Comment: Would this method involve putting this code within the same file as dashboard or as separate files like PersonNameJob.js and PersonNameJob.css?

Comment: If the PersonName component is small, you can put it in the same file with Dashboard. Otherwise, you should define a component each file. CSS should be defined in the component.

Comment: One more thing, you should consider using Functional Component instead of Class Component. Because React Hooks may has better performance but they are designed for Functional Component only. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: I tired putting this part above what I had already written 
```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class PersonNameJob extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div key={index} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Person: {this.props.person.name} , Job: {this.props.person.job}</div>
        );
    }
}

```

But now I receive this error "Line 7:23:  'index' is not defined  no-undef"

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/)? I like to use material UI for things like this. The [Card Component](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/) could be used to easily make what you are looking for. To use material UI you will need to install it using `npm install @material-ui/core` or `yarn add @material-ui/core`. You can then use the components in your components. It would look something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import material UI card components
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
// useful component for displaying text - multiple variants (body, h1, h2 etc.)
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

export class Dashboard extends Component {
    displanyName = Dashboard.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            people: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("api/people")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ people: data }));
    }
    render() {
        //const { people } = this.state; // equivalent to next line
        const people = this.state.people;
        if (people.length > 0)

        //creates an array to iterate
        let arr = people.map((person, index) => (
            <Card key={index}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="h5">
                        Person: {person.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2"> 
                        Job: {person.job}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        ));

        return (
            <div>
                {arr}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Material UI has great documentation (linked above) with full code samples so you can see exactly how everything can be used and how it fits in to your components. I would recommend it if, like me, you struggle a bit with the UI look of components.

Answer (score 0):

your question is looking similar to rendering dynamic components on the fly. checkout this https://gist.github.com/arifshariati/c607a2baf87976f8a2a2ce61c988db4f for dynamic rendering.

for complete example, checkout dynamic form rendering in React and Material UI here https://github.com/arifshariati/react-dynamic-form-drag-drop-redux